# Why does casting unsigned char* to char* require reinterpret_cast?

Tags: c++, c++17

There are many posts on stackoverflow about reading and writing an unsigned char. These posts recommend using `reinterpret_cast` for casting from `unsigned char*` to `char *`. I am wondering why it is needed, as the both types have the same size.

I run the code bellow on Windows and Linux, and it works correct (with or without reinterpret cast). Am I missing something? Can someone post a code which would not work without `reinterpret_cast`? Note, that I am talking about `unsigned char` (not `unsigned int`).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

std::ofstream os;
unsigned char *buff = new unsigned char[3]{ 0xe4, 0xe1, 0xd4 };
os.open("image.jpg", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);

os.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(buff), 3 * sizeof(unsigned char));
// or: os.write((char*)(buff), 3 * sizeof(unsigned char));
os.close();

std::ifstream file;
memset(buff, 0, 3 * sizeof(unsigned char));

file.open("image.jpg", std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(buff), 3 * sizeof(unsigned char));
//or: file.read((char *)buff, 3 * sizeof(unsigned char));
file.close();
```

Comment: better to add a `main()` function for the code

Comment: 'Because both have the same size' doesn't stop it being a typecast.

Comment: For byte buffers, especially there is usually nothing wrong with a C-cast.  But most coding standards will advocate for using `static_cast` or `reinterpret_cast` because it adds clarity to what type of cast is occurring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`reinterpret_cast` is never "needed"; anything a `reinterpret_cast` can do can be done equally well by a C-style cast.

The special cast syntax exists because things that require `reinterpret_cast` tend to be dangerous things and thus attention should probably be called out to those points in code. `reinterpret_cast` also prevents accidentally removing `const`, which a C-style cast will allow you to do.

Comment: It should be noted, though, that a C-style cast, [by definition](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.cast#4), will just perform a `reinterpret_cast` in this case. So *"anything a `reinterpret_cast` can do can be done equally well by a C-style cast"* imho has it a bit backwards. Better not to give an illustion that a C-style cast would somehow be the more general primitive. Quite the opposite actually, a C-style cast in C++ is basically just shorthand notation for "try a bunch of C++ casts and pick the first one that would compile"…

Answer (score 2):

> Why does casting unsigned char* to char* require reinterpret_cast?

C++ is a typed language. Despite having a different size, `unsigned char` and `char` are separate types. Pointer to `unsigned char` and pointer to `char` are also separate types.

C++ language has type safety. The type system is designed to prevent you from making mistakes by disallowing the use of one object as if it were of another, unrelated type. There are implicit conversions from some types to others, which allows creating new objects<sup>1</sup> of one type from objects of another type. Furthermore there are explicit conversions, which allow the same when no implicit conversion exists. One of the explicit conversions allows bypassing the type system completely: Reinterpret casting.

<sup><sup>1</sup> And similarly, you can convert references to new references of other types.</sup>

`char` and `unsigned char` are not related. Pointer to one is not implicitly convertible to a pointer to another. Passing one as argument when the argument has the other type is ill-formed. If you explicitly tell the compiler to ignore the type system, then it won't protect you from the potential mistake of using the wrong type. In this case, the reinterpretation is intentional, and (as far as I can tell) not a mistake. It is these intentional reinterpretations that are the reason for the existence of reinterpret casting.

> I am wondering why it is needed, as the both types have the same size.

The meaning of a type is not wholly described by the size of the type.

---

Note that reinterpret casting is unsafe. There are many rules that must be followed when dealing with reinterpreted pointers / references, and violating any of those rules will result in undefined behaviour. Just because it may be correct here, don't assume that you can use reinterpret casting every time you encounter mismatch with types.

<sup>2</sup> Also note that the C-style cast `(char*)buff` will do reinterpret casting, if there exists no conversion that conforms to the type system. It will also do const casting, which reinterpret casting doesn't do. This makes C-style casts even more unsafe. It is usually recommended to explicitly use the type of cast that you intend to use (static, reinterpret or const cast) rather than C style cast, which performs one or a combination of those, depending on which happen to fit.

> Can someone post a code which would not work without reinterpret_cast?

If you remove `reinterpret_cast`s from your program, then it will be ill-formed. The standard doesn't guarantee that it would work. If you use a compiler that doesn't extend the language, it will likely not work. For example, [GCC refuses to compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b893f486eaee3c04).

Of course, any program that needs `reinterpret_cast` can be rewritten to use a C style cast in its place, because of <sup>2</sup>.

---

P.S. It is usually a better design to avoid casts when you can. In this case, you could use `std::basic_ofstream<unsigned char>` and `std::basic_ifstream<unsigned char>`, and there would be no need for the casts.